# install beautifulsoup4 and bs4

Tags: python

I´ve tried to install beautifulsoup4 and bs4 but it didn´t work.

Python shell mode:

```
>>> import bs4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 250, in <module>
    from .import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 13, in <module>
    from bs4.element import (
  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4.dammit import EntitySubstitution
  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\bs4\dammit.py", line 10, in <module>
    from htmlentitydefs import codepoint2name
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'htmlentitydefs'
```

Comment: It looks like you may have installed the Python 2 version on Python 3.

Comment: I use python 3. What can i do right now to fix this problem. I need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is because you are not importing the module correctly.

Please use  "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" not "import bs4"